# Phonegap 3.4 pushplugin deviceready runs twice

Tags: cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

[image: run twice]

Phonegap pushplugin deviceready runs twice. I have only bind the event once

Attached image.
On phonegap 3.4. Anyone can run this plugin with 3.4 successfully?

Any reason why? I am also not receiving regid even though there is no error message.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pushNotification;

            function onDeviceReady() {
            //alert("onDeviceReady");
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)         {
                 $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

               if( $("#home").length > 0)
                {
                // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
                }       else        {
                navigator.app.backHistory();
                }
        }, false);

        try     {
                 pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                 if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                    // ecb: event callback that gets called when your device receives a notification
                        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"8701masked","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});   // required!
                    } else {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                        pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                    }
                }
            catch(err)
            {
            txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
            txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
            alert(txt);
            }


         }// end of device ready

            // handle APNS notifications for iOS
            onNotificationAPN = function(e) {
                if (e.alert) {
                     $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                     navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
                }

                if (e.sound) {
                    var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                    snd.play();
                }

                if (e.badge) {
                    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
                }
            };

            // handle GCM notifications for Android
            onNotificationGCM = function(e) {
            //function onNotificationGCM(e) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

                switch( e.event )
                {
                    case 'registered':
                    alert("registered:"+ e.regid);
                    if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                    {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                    }
                    break;

                    case 'message':
                     // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                     // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                     if (e.foreground)               {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                    // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                    var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                    my_media.play();
                    }else{  // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                        if (e.coldstart)
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    break;

                    case 'error':
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;

                    default:
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
                }
            };

            function tokenHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
                // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
            }

            //  - called when a plugin method returns without error
            function successHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
            }

            function errorHandler (error) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
            }

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

         </script>
```

Comment: Not sure this will answer but why do you have ,true in you addEventListener ?
This is the only things which "surprise" me

Comment: Hi, you managed to make it work in Phonegap 3.4? I have tried many ways.. installed 3.0 - 3.4 and even cordova... all have the success message but no regid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620218/phonegap-push-plugin-not-working-on-android-4-0-4-and-below

Answer (score 1):

Solved after reinstall phonegap .