# PhoneGap Push Plugin Not working on android 4.0.4 and below

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I could successfully run plugin and saved register id on galaxy s3, note 2, note 3 but it's not working on two different samsung galaxy mini device 2.3.6 and 4.0.4.

What could be the solution ?

Official plug-in link:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

here is the video of the problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2wdFDQc1aI

working well on my galaxy s3 though:

[image]

Comment: What error or notify?

Comment: There isn't any error message. last and crucial part is not working, which is "REGID"  @HanhLe

Comment: @HanhLe here is the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2wdFDQc1aI here is the apk file www.obscepte.com/pushtest.apk

Comment: I not download apk from your url( i not see what issue, i test plugin in android 2.3.6 and 4.0.4, it working), i think it is not error, that is register event from GCM not send to your device. You should check, device must have a google account added.

Comment: NOPE it's definetly not working. here is the link of source code of this project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28301519/quickpush3.zip

AND it seems you didn't read my question. SAME project SAME apk file is working on Galaxy S3, Note 2, Note 3. But it's not working on few  other devices which has lower android versions.

Comment: Yes, device not receive any event from GCM(several device). I don't know why, and i reinstall plugin via CLI and it working well

Comment: May be I am very late to comment but for people searching for an answer similar to this question would like to notify that this plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin is deprecated. This is the working official link for the Phonegap Push Plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push which works fine for all Api levels. If things are fine with your server and your device gets registered successfully, clearing Storage cache and System's partition cache may help. Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127914/phonegap-push-plugin-not-working-in-nougat